# Recursive method is returning first iteration object C#

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    token objtoken = new token();
    var location = AddLocations();
    OutPutResults outPutResultsApi = new OutPutResults();
    GCPcall gCPcall = new GCPcall();
    
    OutPutResults finaloutPutResultsApi = new OutPutResults();
    var addressdt = new AddressDataDetails();
    finaloutPutResultsApi.addressDatas = new List<AddressDataDetails>();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    List<string> placeId = new List<string>();
    var baseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?";
    var apiKey = "&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".Trim();
    foreach (var itemlocations in location)
    {
        var searchtext = "query=" + itemlocations.Trim();
        var finalUrl = baseUrl + searchtext + apiKey;
        gCPcall.RecursiveApiCall(finalUrl, ref placeId, objtoken.NextToken);
    }
    var ids = gCPcall.myPalceid;
}
```

```
public List<string> RecursiveApiCall(string finalUrl, ref List<string> placeId, string nextToken = null)
{
    try
    {
        var token = "&pagetoken=" + nextToken;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync(finalUrl + token);
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                readTask.Wait();
                var students = readTask.Result;
                Rootobject studentsmodel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(students);
                nextToken = studentsmodel.next_page_token;
                foreach (var item in studentsmodel.results)
                {
                    placeId.Add(item.place_id);
                }
            }
        }
        if (nextToken != null)
        { 
             RecursiveApiCall(finalUrl, ref placeId, nextToken);
        }
        
        return placeId;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

My recursive method has some issue. Here whenever I am debugging this code it work fine. It goes in recursive call twice.
As debugging result I am getting list `place_id` with 20 items in first call and next call 9 items total 29 items in `place_id` object which is correct in static main method.

But if I run without debugging mode I am getting only 20 `place_id`. next recursive iteration data is missing even if it has next valid token.
I don't have any clue why this is happening. Can someone tell me what is the issue with my code?

Comment: Unrelated: Some issues - 1. [You are using HttpClient wrong](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) 2. `ref` on `placeId` is completely unneccessary.

Comment: `responseTask.Wait();` - that's a NoNo. `readTask.Wait();` - that's a NoNo. Go async all the way.

Comment: And finally: Why recursion if you can do this perfectly fine with a simple loop?

Comment: @Fildor I have to iterate next page from api call with next page token

Comment: Exactly. No recursion needed, whatsoever.

Comment: @Fildor then how could i call that method again without recursion with next page ?

Comment: Not at all. You loop inside. There is no point in using recursion here. It just makes everything more complicated as it needs to be. I'm in a hurry now, I'll write up a suggestion later.

Comment: @Fildor thanks I will wait for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions, which may or may not solve the problem:

```
// First of all, let's fix the signature : Go async _all the way_
//public List<string> RecursiveApiCall(string finalUrl, ref List<string> placeId, string nextToken = null)
// also reuse the HttpClient!
public async Task ApiCallAsync(HttpClient client, string finalUrl, List<string> placeId, string nextToken = null)
{
    // Loop, don't recurse
    while(!(nextToken is null)) // C# 9: while(nextToken is not null)
    {
        try
        {
            var token = "&pagetoken=" + nextToken;
            // again async all the way
            var result = await client.GetAsync(finalUrl+token);

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // async all the way!
                var students = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Rootobject studentsmodel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(students);
                nextToken = studentsmodel.next_page_token;
                foreach (var item in studentsmodel.results)
                {
                    // Will be reflected in main, so no need to return or `ref` keyword
                    placeId.Add(item.place_id);
                }
            }

// NO recursion needed!
//        if (nextToken != null)
//        { 
//             RecursiveApiCall(finalUrl, ref placeId, nextToken);
//        }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // rethrow, only is somewhat useless
            // I'd suggest using a logging framework and 
            // log.Error(ex, "Some useful message");
            throw;

            // OR remove try/catch here all together and wrap the call to this method
            // in try / catch with logging.
        }
}
```

Mind that you'll need to make your main :

```
async Task Main(string[] args)
```

and call this as

```
await ApiCallAsync(client, finalUrl, placeId, nextToken);
```

Also create an HttpClient in main and reuse that:

> *"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors."* - [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0#remarks)

... which shouldn't do much harm here, but it's a "best practice" anyhow.

---

Now, as to why you get only 20 instead of expected 29 items, I cannot say if this resolves that issue. I'd highly recommend to introduce a Logging Framework and make log entries accordingly, so you may find the culprid.

Comment: @Filder this not working when it come first time with null value while (!(nextToken is null)) // C# 9: while(nextToken is not null)

Comment: @Filder thank for great inside, I used Do,while now its work as expected. Cheers !!!

Comment: @Filder thank for great inside, I used Do,while now its work as expected in debugged mode, still having same issue .

Comment: @samikshadaware Ok, that would hint to that the token is null. You expect 2 iterations with 1: 20 items, 2: 9 items, you do 1 run regardless of whether token is null, so get 20, in the result of that query, you expect a token to be non-null to go on with the second iteration. But **is it**?

Comment: @Filder Yes, you understand correctly, but still I am not getting expected place_id=29. Still I am getting 20 Items. :-( Struggling from afternoon. But no luck.

Comment: @Filder Do while not working as expected, I traces the logs